# Vectors and co-linearity

Tags: vectors

If two vectors a and b are non-collinear, then for what values of x are the vectors $$c = (x-2)a + b$$ and $$d = (3 + 2x)a - 2b$$ collinear?

No idea how to even approach the problem. I attempted drawing a diagram, but it didn't seem to help. Please point in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you a hint, if **c** and **d** are co-linear for certain value of x then that means the angle between them is zero. Hence cross product **c** x **d** = 0

Now all you gotta do is solve the equation:

(3+2x) + 2(x-2) = 0

Comment: But the angle being zero may also signify that the two vectors are parallel?

Comment: 2 vectors are co-linear if one is a constant 'k' times the other.
If you did solve the equation and plug in the values, you'll find that **d** = -2 **c**

Comment: That's what I got.  Well thank you!